# How to inject component-specific values into a service?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

It is clear to me how we can inject a service. We can provide the service either at the module level, or at the component level.

I wish to inject a specific property to the service before that service in turn is injected into my component. The property in question is dependent on my component.

How can this be achieved in Angular 2?

Example:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(myProperty: string) {
    setSomethingUsingMyProperty(myProperty)
  }
}

@Component(..., {providers: [MyService] })
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(myService: MyService) {
    myService.doSomething()
  }
}
```

If I'd provide the property in the overlying module, I presume Angular can inject the property if I include the `@Inject` directive. But how can this be achieved at the component level?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can provide and inject by string name like

```ts
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(@Inject('someName') myProperty: String) {
    setSomethingUsingMyProperty(myProperty)
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({..., 
  providers: [MyService, {provide: 'someName', useValue: 'someValue'}] })
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(myService: MyService) {
    myService.doSomething()
  }
}
```

Comment: I had presumed that providing using `useValue` would only apply to MyComponent, for example if the MyComponent constructor requests an injection of `someName`. How come this resolves the DI requirement of MyService? What would happen if i injected a component MySecondComponent into MyComponent, which already provides `someName` to itself with a different value? Thanks a lot for your support by the way.

Comment: If you provide `MyService` on `@NgModule` instead of `@Component` this wouldn't work. When DI creates an instance of a provider it starts at other providers of the same injector (in my answer this is the injector of the component), if it doesn't find a provider, it looks at the parents component injector until it reaches `AppComponent`. If it can't find a provider there it looks up the providers provided by `@NgModule`. In my answer. the provider is found on the first location it looks for it and it's injected. You can't inject other components except a parent.

Comment: When the parent provides `someName` but the current component doesn't, then according to above rule, it will find it on the 2nd location where DI looks for it.

Comment: I see! It would not work on `@NgModule` because i am providing `someValue` at a lower point in the hierarchy. And if a parent also provides `someValue` it would pick that from `MyComponent` instead of the parent since it is the first location it checks. Thank you for your concise explanation!

Comment: Exactly . . . . .. . .. ... .. .